# PHP script end whit FATAL-ERROR when error in fromArray() parameter, impossible to catch the error

Tags: phpspreadsheet

This code has an error :

```
$arrayDebug = [["a","B"],"C"];  // ["a","b"] is an array, not a string
try {
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->fromArray(
        $arrayDebug,
        null, "A2");
}catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getTrace(),'Stacktrace '.__LINE__;
}
```

because ["a","b"] is an array, not a string.

there is a FATAL ERROR :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: preg_match(): Argument 
#2 ($subject) must be of type string, array given in D:\users\Mick5\Documents\GitHub\EC-recondapi.git\libraries\spreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php:64 Stack trace: 
#0 D:...\libraries\spreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php(64): preg_match('/^[\\+\\-]?(\\d+\\....', Array) 
#1 D:...\libraries\spreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php(35): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder::dataTypeForValue(Array) 
#2 D:...\libraries\spreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell.php(190): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder->bindValue(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell), Array) 
#3 D:...\libraries\spreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet.php(2514): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell->setValue(Array) 
#4 D:...\public\xtestfatalerror.php(15): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet->fromArray(Array, NULL, 'A2') 
#5 {main} thrown in D:...\libraries\spreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php on line 64
```

I undestand my error.

My problem is that I can't catch this error.

How can I avoid script to end ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and found an easy solution for that.
Check your array and make sure each array inside your parent array is not empty and make sure all of them are of the same length.
For me, it was the last line which was in fact an empty line from the CSV file that I used to convert it to an array that resulted in the above error. Just removing that line help me resolve that error.